# Can there exist a non diagonal matrix whose inverse is diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am just curious, this thing came in my research. Here I mean strictly non-diagonal matrix.(I have used the word strictly for those people who think diagonal matrix is also a non-diagonal matrix whose off-diagonal entries are zero.)

Comment: I am talking about square matrices whose inverse exist (nullity is zero). Don't bring pseduo-inverse, right-inverse, left-inverse etc all those stuff here.

Comment: The inverse matrix of a diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ is the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(\frac{1}{\lambda_1}, \ldots, \frac{1}{\lambda_n})$ and the inverse is unique so no.

Comment: is it like it in a vector space or field, every element has a unique inverse?

Comment: Yes, it is like in a field with respect to addition or multiplication or like in a vector space with respect to addition.

Answer (score 1):

No, any invertible matrix is the inverse of the inverse of itself, and the inverse of any invertible diagonal matrix is itself diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a diagonal matrix $A$ is also diagonal (the elements on its diagonal being the inverses of the diagonal elements of $A$). Suppose $B$ is such that $B^{-1}$ is diagonal then so is $(B^{-1})^{-1}=B$.